# Como organizar necessidades da UI no DDD

Tags: c#, design-pattern, ddd

Aonde coloco o codigo que não diz respeito a regra de negocio, mas é uma necessidade para a apresentação ao usuario, como preenchimento de combobox, dataTables, texboxAutoComplit...?

detalhes:

Atualmente trabalho em camadas (presentation, application, domain, data...) tentamos modelar o mais próximo possível da regra de negocio usando a linguagem ubiquá, separando contextos delimitados, criando agregados,entidades,objetos valor ... pacote completo DDD, porem quando chega no momento de desenvolver a presentation acabamos "sujanto" algumas interfaces com metodos para atender a demanda de frameworks de exibição. Para estas consultas estamos referenciando o data ao presentation porem mesmo assim ainda não fica bom o suficiente.

Comment: É Web, Mobile, Desktop?

Comment: todos na verdade hehehe, é uma presentation para cada interface de usuario, em alguns projetos pode ter só uma em outros umas 5, depende muito....

Comment: Pra mim ainda continua confuso a ideia de, por exemplo, preenchimento de combobox, você diz como eu vou dizer o que sera inserido dentro do combobox?

Comment: Deixa eu tentar de outro jeito:
Você tem um produto, ele tem comportamentos, atributos, serviços de domino, serviços e repositório padrao CRUD, eis que surge no horizonte, a necessidade de implementar um dataTable para o fornt end. para isso vc vai precisar de uns 3 metodos; esses metodos não tem nada haver com o negocio/comportamento do Produto, então aonde coloco eles? junto com os metodos CRUD "sujando" o comportamento? ou em outro lugar (que não sei onde) para ficar separado?.... Entendeu? :)

Comment: Você menciona a necessidade de 3 métodos...só pra entender sua situação: qual seria a finalidade dos mesmos?

Comment: seria tipo: buscar o produto de acordo com o que a api do dataTablepede(https://datatables.net/); ou buscar uma lista com a descriçao e o id para popular no combobox; ou uma lista paginada para apresentaçao; ou qqr coisa parecida que voce precise somente para o usuario final mas que não tenha nada a ver com o negocio...

Comment: Para a paginação eu não vejo problema, acredito que sempre deve haver paginação nas queries, mas uma paginação opcional(`skip` e `limit`, que podem ser zero e aí o método não pagina o resultado). Quanto a lista com descrição e id, pra mim isso é responsabilidade da camada Presentation, ela vai obter o Produto como ele é, e vai fazer o mapeamento do seu view model. O mesmo se aplica para como produto será exibido pelo DataTable, é um view model, e cabe à presentation adaptar o produto às suas necessidades de exibição.